# TypeError: remove() argument must be xml.etree.ElementTree.Element, not str | python | xml.etree

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to remove specific attribute across my xml file

wherever it comes need to remove all **tag** : "`name`"  `->` `<name> </name>`

**Data :**

```
<data>
  <row>
    <index>0</index>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</desc>
    <calories>650</calories>
  <foodid>A123#</foodid></row>
  <row>
    <index>1</index>
    <price>$7.95</price>
    <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</desc>
    <calories>900</calories>
  <foodid>A123#</foodid></row>
  <row>
    <index>2</index>
    <price>$8.95</price>
    <name>Berry-Berry Belgian Waffles</name>
    <desc>Light Belgian waffles covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</desc>
    <calories>900</calories>
  <foodid>A123#</foodid></row>
  <row>
    <index>3</index>
    <price>$4.50</price>
    <name>French Toast</name>
    <desc>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</desc>
    <calories>600</calories>
  <foodid>A123#</foodid></row>
  <row>
    <index>4</index>
    <price>$6.95</price>
    <name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
    <desc>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</desc>
    <calories>950</calories>
  <foodid>A123#</foodid></row>
</data>
```

**My code :**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random

parse_xml = ET.parse('/content/sample_data/xyz.xml')
get_root_element = parse_xml.getroot()

for data in get_root_element:
  for item in data:
    data.remove(item.tag)

#get_root_element[0][0].attrib.pop("name", None)
  
#get_root_element[1][0].attrib.pop("name",None)
parse_xml.write('/content/sample_data/abc.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import random

parse_xml = ET.parse('/content/sample_data/xyz.xml')
get_root_element = parse_xml.getroot()

for data in get_root_element:
  for item in data:
    if item.tag == "name":
      data.remove(item)
    else:
      pass

parse_xml.write('/content/sample_data/abc.xml')
```